# Java: creating an object in 3 single steps (Declaration, Allocation/Initialization, Assignment)

Tags: java, object, initialization, declaration

I am not sure about the definiton of Declaration and Initialization. And when is setting the **Default Values Initialization**.

1) For example the **Declaration** of the object rocky (class Dog):

```
Dog rocky;
```

This creates only an entry in the stack and there is no reference?

.

2) Creating an **Instance** of Dog:

```
new Dog();
```

**Memory Allocation** in the Heap, **Default Values Initialization** (variable `legs` to `0`), create a **Reference**.

If I have no constructor: the compiler creates a default constructor. Is it empty? 
**Constructor** and **Default Values Initialization** have to be different kettle of fish and is one of the possible Instance Initializer (next **Instance Initializer Block** and **Constructor**).

.

3) **Assignment**: put the Reference-Value into the stack?

```
rocky = new Dog();
```

Am I right?

Thanks

**Sample:**

```
class Dog
{
    int legs;

    Dog()
        {
            System.out.println("constructor invoked");
        }
}

public class Foo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Dog rocky;

            new Dog();

            rocky = new Dog();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following allocates memory for a pointer to a `Dog` object:

```
Dog rocky;
```

The following allocates memory for a `Dog` object:

```
new Dog();
```

And the following allocates memory for a `Dog` pointer and a `Dog` object and sets the pointer's value to the memory location of the newly created `Dog` object:

```
Dog rocky = new Dog();
```

-

The compiler writes the default initialization into each Constructor you defined. If you don't define one, the compiler creates a default one.
Example:

```
int legs = 4;
```

will be converted to

```
int legs;
public Dog() {
    legs = 4;
}
```

The default inizialisations are the first statements in your constructor.